# A question about cyclic subgroup of $S_3$

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $H\le S_3$ generated by the $3$-cycle $(123) \in S_3$.

So we should have $H = \{(123), (312), e\}$ where $e = (1)(2)(3)$.

What I don't understand is, which is respectively, the inverse of these elements?

Because if I do, for example

- $$(123)(312) = (312)$$
- $$(312)(123) = (312)$$

while I would expect to obtain the identity element $e$..

EDIT:

So $H$ is the wrong subgroup. But to show the isomorphism what I do is considering the injective map

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_3 &\rightarrow S_3\\
n&\mapsto (123)^n
\end{align}

and so this would lead $e$ for $n=0$, $(123)$ for $n=1$, $(123)^2 = (312)$ for $n=2$.. Is this the wrong way to consider this identification?

Comment: $(123)$ and $(312)$ are actually the same permutation.

Comment: $H$ is wrong, and incidentally, so are your evaluations of the products. In fact $(123)=(312)$, and $(123)(312)=(312)(123)=(123)^2=(132)$. You should have $H=\{(123),(132),e\}$, and then $(123)(132)=e$.

Comment: Thanks.. I have edited the question with some additional perplexities..